# Query with opposite functionality of IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to return image name which is in one of the target ids 1, 2 or 3

```
SELECT AI.ACCESSORY_IMAGE_NAME, P.PART_CODE, PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID, PT.TARGET_NAME FROM ASS.ACCESSORY_IMAGE AI
JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI ON PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID =  AI.ACCESSORY_IMAGE_ID and PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'ACCESSORY_IMAGE'
JOIN PRD.ACCESSORY A ON A.ACCESSORY_ID = AI.ACCESSORY_ID
JOIN PRD.PART P ON P.PART_ID = A.PART_ID
JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID = PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID AND PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID in (1,2,3)
WHERE AI.ACCESSORY_IMAGE_NAME = 'fire_ext.jpg'
```

which returns as the image is published in target id 1

```
ACCESSORY_IMAGE_NAME    PART_CODE           PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID     TARGET_NAME
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fire_ext.jpg            PZ4AC-00EF0-EU      1                       DEALER_ACCESS
```

But I want to return the targets where the image is not published. In this case it is 2 and 3

**Expected output**

```
ACCESSORY_IMAGE_NAME    PART_CODE           PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID     TARGET_NAME
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fire_ext.jpg            PZ4AC-00EF0-EU      2                       INTERNET
fire_ext.jpg            PZ4AC-00EF0-EU      3                       INTRANET
```

The "NOT IN" operator does not return any rows obviously as the image is published in target 1.

Comment: By which column you come to know that image is published or not? I mean how you decide that image is published or not?

Comment: If the entry is there in PUBLISHED_TARGET, it means that it is published.

Comment: You mean if PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID = NULL, it is not published right?

Comment: Thanks for the response, it got resolved with Joao answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the last join to

```
JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID <> PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID
```

Comment: @Techie . . . I would be highly surprised if this really does work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am also surprised. Cause his question is not clear enough.

Comment: Hi Gordon, it did work. I tried left join but it did not work

Comment: I wrote a small test and it does indeed work, unfortunatly SQLFiddle is down at the moment.  Honest question, why is it so surprising that this solution works?    Regarding the solution @GordonLinoff presented, it doesn't work because it uses the same `PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET` column to join this table with `PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM` and to check for no matches.

Comment: I agree Joao. The first thing I tried is left join but as I have not null column, so it does not work. Appreciate your efforts and Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "published" means.  If it means being in the `published_target` table, then use a `left join` and check for no matches:

```
SELECT AI.ACCESSORY_IMAGE_NAME, P.PART_CODE, PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID, PT.TARGET_NAME FROM ASS.ACCESSORY_IMAGE AI
JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI ON PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID =  AI.ACCESSORY_IMAGE_ID and PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'ACCESSORY_IMAGE'
JOIN PRD.ACCESSORY A ON A.ACCESSORY_ID = AI.ACCESSORY_ID
JOIN PRD.PART P ON P.PART_ID = A.PART_ID
LEFT JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID = PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID AND PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID in (1,2,3)
WHERE AI.ACCESSORY_IMAGE_NAME = 'fire_ext.jpg' and PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID IS NULL;
```

The same idea would hold for any table.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the response, I did try this before but PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID is a  not null column. So it did not work.

Comment: Hi Gordon, is there any way of achieving the results without using "<>" operator ?

Comment: @Techie . . . Being a `not null` column has no effect on this query.  The `NULL` would be the result of not matching -- which appears to be what you want.